# NullPointerException I cannot resolve

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

This is the method called when the player has to be removed from the game. Both these methods are in different classes.

**GameboardGUI class**

```
    Vector<Player> players = new Vector<Player>();

    public void removePlayerFromGame(Player playerToRemove)
        {
            //go through the playerToRemove's properties and reset all their variables
            for(int i = 0; i < playerToRemove.getPropertiesOwned().size(); i++)
            {
                //code to reset the player's properties to an unowned/unmodified state
            }
            //same with transports
            for(int i = 0; i < playerToRemove.getTransportsOwned().size(); i++)
            {
                //code to reset the player's transports to an unowned/unmodified state
            }
            //just updating the vector based on the playerToRemove's position
            if(players.get(0) == playerToRemove)
            {
                players.remove(playerToRemove);
                updatePlayerInformation();
            }
            else 
            {
                players.remove(playerToRemove);
                updatePlayerVector(players);
                updatePlayerInformation();
            }

        }
```

This is how the method is called:
If the current player (fromMe) lands on a property and cant afford to pay the rent (i.e. their balance reaches 0 as a result of `takefrombalance(1200);`, currently hardcoded to 1200 to make testing easier) they are removed in the if statement `if(fromMe.isBankrupt())`

**Property Class**

```
GameboardGUI gui = new GameboardGUI();

public void payRent(Player fromMe, Player toYou, int rent)
    {
        //remove rent from the current player
        fromMe.takeFromBalance(1200);
        //add it to the owner
        toYou.addToBalance(rent);
        GameboardGUI.addGameFeedMessage(fromMe.getName() + " has paid " + rent + " in rent to " + toYou.getName());
        GameboardGUI.addGameFeedMessage(toYou.getName() + "'s balance is now " + toYou.getBalance());
        if(fromMe.isBankrupt())
        {
            //THIS IS THE CALL THAT THROWS THE NullPointerException
            gui.removePlayerFromGame(fromMe);
        }
        else 
        {
            GameboardGUI.addGameFeedMessage(fromMe.getName() + "'s balance is now " + fromMe.getBalance());
        }
    }
```

Here is the stack trace when the line is reached:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at PropertyTile.payRent(PropertyTile.java:254)
    at PropertyTile.landedOnProperty(PropertyTile.java:239)
    at GameboardGUI.playerHasLanded(GameboardGUI.java:1905)
    at Player.setPosition(Player.java:82)
    at Player.movePlayer(Player.java:101)
    at GameboardGUI$11.actionPerformed(GameboardGUI.java:1536)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Basically the method call gui.removePlayerFromGame(fromMe); is to remove the player 'fromMe' from the game as they cannot afford to pay rent. It throws an null pointer exception for that line. I cannot find out why. That's the only code that is relevant to that method.

Comment: Did you tried debugging?, Where is gui defined?

Comment: @IEatSandvich Stack Trace please? and where is `gui`? I dont see it anywhere in `Class` class

Comment: I can't see gui being instantiated anywhere

Comment: What line is 254 within property tile?

Comment: @IEatSandvich Can you show us the code where you call `payRent(Player fromMe, Player toYou, int rent)` and how you initialize the `fromMe` object. Also can you include the 2 if statements from my answer and tell us if you get 1 of the two messages.

Answer (score 1):

It's **really** hard to help you without a stacktrace and the line numbers for your code, but we're trying.

If that's really the line (and not actually within `removePlayerFromGame`), the member `gui` hasn't been initialized.

Of course, if it's not that line, it could simply be that `playerToRemove` is null, and the NullPointerException is actually happening a couple of lines above.

Or, another possibility is that it's happening within `removePlayerFromGame`, in which case the most likely case is that `playerToRemove` hasn't been properly set up - that its `getPropertiesOwned()` or `getTransportsOwned()` methods are returning null.

Comment: It has been. At the top of the class it's initialised GameboardGUI gui = new GameboardGUI(); (Yet I didnt show that, sorry)

Comment: and `players` in the GameboardGUI class being a `Vector<Player> players;`

Comment: I've had a few people read over the code and no one can see anything wrong syntactically with the code. I was sort of hoping someone might know just from experience what the issue may be..

Comment: @IEatSandvich please update the post with that info, and can you post the stack trace?

Comment: @IEatSandwich How do you know it's a nullpointerexception if you haven't seen a stack trace?  Are you catching the exception?  The default behavior for an uncaught exception is to print the stacktrace - you don't have to do anything, it just happens.

Comment: What "debug window"?  Where are you doing this?

Comment: The stack trace is in the OP.

`line 254` being the line `gui.removePlayerFromGame(fromMe);`

Comment: @CPerkins I've tried everything you're saying. And tried meewoK's suggestion below and neither return null. Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: @IEatSandvich In addition to meewok's, try these lines:
if (fromMe.getPropertiesOwned() == null)
System.out.println ( "fromMe.getPropertiesOwned() is null");
if (fromMe.getTransportsOwned() == null)
System.out.println ( "fromMe.getTransportsOwned() is null");

Comment: Tried that before, it's fine. :/ Will try rewriting. If I manage to resolve it, seems unlikely at this stage, I'll post the solution.

Comment: @IEatSandvich Try that again, in one small program which compiles and demonstrates the problem, and post that.  There's something you're missing.

Answer (score 0):

I would add the following two lines, as a first step to see what happens:

```
if(fromMe==null)
System.out.println("from me is null");

if(gui == null)
System.out.println("gui is null"); 

gui.removePlayerFromGame(fromMe);
```

One of the two object references is null causing the exception. 
Otherwise, the method removePlayerFromGame is doing something, but I don't think that would be the case because the stacktrace would include additional methods.

Comment: Are you getting the stack trace / error every time or sometimes? Maybe your getting if it you click a button two times?

Comment: Keep getting it. I've had things like this before where if I just delete the code and retype it, it will end up working. Might completely rewrite it. Do it a bit differently. See if it will work a different way. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You say in the code that the Exception is thrown when you reach the line

```
gui.removePlayerFromGame(fromMe);
```

However, the top of stacktrace you are showing is Player.movePlayer(), with its bottom at PropertyTile.payRent().

Is this payRent() receiving any parameter? Can you post it source?